# Invoice format recognizer

Tags: parsing

I'm working with an application that receives all text from an invoice (text was get by processing the scanned image of that invoice). Now, because there're several invoice formats that are available so I need to categorize what format the application is receiving. For example some format may contains number of unit, some don't (but they both have total cost).

I did some research on parsing techniques but found no workable solution for this. Do you have any suggestion for this type of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl, you can use [Marpa](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2), a general BNF parser — describe your invoice format in BNF and Marpa will parse your invoices accordng to the BNF, see e.g. how it tackled this [complex example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167132/parsing-of-parenthesis-with-sed-using-regex/26168693) with this [simple code](https://gist.github.com/rns/3537965d905bf34c1b66).