# Parsing of parenthesis with sed using regex

Tags: python, regex, perl, sed

I am looking for a command in `sed` which transforms this input stream:

```
dummy
(key1)
(key2)dummy(key3)
dummy(key4)dummy
dummy(key5)dummy))))dummy
dummy(key6)dummy))(key7)dummy))))
```

into this one:

```
key1
key2
key3
key4
key5
key6
key7
```

where `dummy` can be any string without parenthesis. So I basically would like to extract the strings in-between the parenthesis and output one string per line. There can be extra closing parenthesis `)`.

I ran many tests with `sed` using regex, but I can't figure out
how to solve this problem. Though I am sure it is possible.
(I am open to alternative tools like Perl or Python for instance)

EDIT : The string between parenthesis (key1, key2 .. key7) can be any string without parenthesis.

Comment: `cat input | perl -nle'print $1 if /(key\d+)/` You should post the code you've tried too when you ask questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookbehind based regex in `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=\()[^)]+' file
key1
key2
key3
key4
key5
key6
key7
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk -F '[()]' 'NF>1{for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) if ($i) print $i}' file
key1
key2
key3
key4
key5
key6
key7
```

Comment: Thanks. I pick your solution. It works with quite general strings. In fact, I tried this file and it went through :

    duxxmmy
    (test1)
    (k./\ey2)du./\mmy(ke3zb\.\/ouby3)
    du.\/\ddmmy(key44.\/\44)dum\/\/ffmy
    duddmmy(key55_[]-_55_5)dumppmy))))duaaammy
    dumrrmy(6key-_[].\/.6)drrummy))(key7)dddummy))))

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perlishly I'd do:

```
my @all_keys; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
   push ( @all_keys, m/\((.+?)\)/g  );
}
print join ("\n",@all_keys);


__DATA__
dummy
(key1)
(key2)dummy(key3)
dummy(key4)dummy
dummy(key5)dummy))))dummy
dummy(key6)dummy))(key7)dummy))))
```

This assumes that 'keys' match the `\w` in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (alphanumeric plus "_",)

(If you're not familiar with perl, you can pretty much just swap that `<DATA>` for `<STDIN>` and pipe the data straight to your script - or do more interesting things with `@all_keys`)

Comment: I tried this solution. Indeed it works with alphanumerical strings, but keys string can be any string without parenthesis, and in my case, I am going to use it for filename with paths, meaning it can have special chars like / \ . [ ] - _ Thanks for your time anyway, I created my first perl script ;-)

Comment: You can do broader matching with `m/\((.+?)\)/g` - `.` denotes any character type, but minimal matching with the `?`. Just watch out for filenames with brackets in them.

Comment: (Answer amended accordingly - does it work with your sample data now?)

Comment: It also works indeed. Thanks. (It seems I cant tick mark on top left for both answers. I chose the shortest one.)

Comment: Wouldn't worry about it - multiple valid answers is no bad thing. If it doesn't help you now, it may help someone asking the same question later.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, you can use [Marpa](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2), a general BNF parser — the parser code is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rns/3537965d905bf34c1b66).

BNF parser is arguably more maintainable than a regex.  Parens around grammar symbols hide their values from the parse tree thus simplifying the post-processing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.

Comment: Great, BTW, just tested duxxmmy (test1) (k./\ey2)du./\mmy(ke3zb\.\/ouby3) du.\/\ddmmy(key44.\/\44)dum\/\/ffmy duddmmy(key55_[]-_55_5)dumppmy))))duaaammy dumrrmy(6key-_[].\/.6)drrummy))(key7)dddummy)))) output is test1
k./\ey2
ke3zb\.\/ouby3
key44.\/\44
key55_[]-_55_5
6key-_[].\/.6
key7